# Are time and distance state or process variables?

Tags: thermodynamics

So this is my thought process:
I think time is a state variable, while distance is, simply because time is time and has no "path" i.e. distance, dependence. Same goes to explain as to why distance would be a process variable.

I am not sure my reasoning makes sense, though. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: In my judgment, both time and distance are process variables.

Comment: Why do you think so? If you don't mind me asking, just trying to understand.

Comment: I agree with Chet. Force is a process variable, namely, when it is combined with distance or displacement, it is a work process variable.

Comment: A variable is basically a coordinate which defines the state of a system. It can't be state or process variable. Like for a hydrostatic system, pressure, volume, temperature and amount are variables that defines the state of the system. But all these variables are not state or path variables. It is the internal energy which is state function or work which is path function. So coordinates by themselves are not state or path variables (they can be intensive or extensive), they just define the trajectory of the transition between two states of a system (called process).

Comment: It is the quantities which gets transacted (or exchanged) has associated meaning of state or path dependence. Like for a different paths between two states defined by coordinates, same amount of internal energy is changed or not. Likewise I don't think force is a state or path variable work done by force can be path (in case of dissipation of energy) or non-path variable (in presence of only conservative force field). I might be incorrect also.

Comment: If you take a system from state A to state B and check the time, when you then take the system back to  state A, has the time returned to its original value?

Comment: I am afraid that without a previous definition of the meaning of *state variable* and *process variable*  there is no way to answer. Even *distance* would require clarification. Distance between two moving objects may be classified differently as the distance between two fixed walls.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit vague. I think if the system described by the variables time and distance is moving through space and time, then they are both process variables, while if the system is stationary in our frame of reference we could argue time is a process variable while distance is a state variable. Does this make sense?